# timestamp on messages is wrong

Tags: sms, zte-racer

1. My phone is turned off
2. 11:00 - My friend sends me a text message/sms
3. 2:00 - I turn my phone on.
4. 2:01 - I receive the text message/sms, the timestamp is 2:01
5. But I want the timestamp to be 11:00

How do I get this to happen? I am on a [ZTE Racer](http://www.gsmarena.com/zte_racer-3423.php) on [giffgaff](http://giffgaff.com/) in the UK. I have Android 2.1, Eclair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug in the Android source but no particular action seems to have been taken. You can follow and star the issue [on the Android bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2989).

Alternatively, [one comment on the bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2989#c136) notes some potential workarounds you an take a look at:

> Just an additional comment for all those still waiting for this bug to
>   be fixed: current version of Handcent saves the "sent time" of the
>   messages. It can be seen on "message details". It's not the perfect
>   solution but it's the best solution that we have right now.
>
> "SMS
>   Timestamper Fix" from andrperk worked for me most of the times but not
>   always.

Additionally, some commenters have reported that certain handsets do not suffer from this bug, presumably because the manufacturer patched it themselves in their messaging application or SMS framework.